# Machine Learning: predicting a new value in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

Just follow a ML tutorial (https://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-r-step-by-step/). I'm trying to predict a single output on a single vector.

I'm using the IRIS dataset, and trying to predict with an LDA Algorythm.
I'm trying to use my nval vector (c(4.3,3.1,1.5,0.1) to predict a single outcome, what Species is it?

```
fit.lda <- train(Species~., data=dataset, method="lda", metric=metric, 
trControl=control)
predictions <- predict(fit.lda, validation)
```

This gives a regular output, as expected.

```
predict(fit.lda, nval)
```

Gives me:

*Warning message:
'newdata' had 4 rows but variables found have 120 rows*

Help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(caret)
control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)
metric <- "Accuracy"

validation_index <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p=0.80, list=FALSE)
validation <- iris[-validation_index,]
dataset <- iris[validation_index,]  

fit.lda <- train(Species~., data=dataset, method="lda", metric=metric, 
                 trControl=control)
```

You need to define `nval`as a data frame with columns named as in `iris`

```
nval <- data.frame(4.3, 3.1, 1.5, 0.1)
names(nval) <- names(iris)[1:4]
predict(fit.lda, nval)

# [1] setosa
```